Custom Windows Registry ID for WinUI 3 Notifications
enter image description here
How can I get a custom ID/Name for my WinUI3 program with notifications? Each time I start the unpacked program through the debugger or the .exe itself from any location, it creates a random GUID like "{A67659DD-0AD9-4430-BCE0-9658AD0E69EC}" under the path:

HKEY_USERS(SID)\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\

As I want to manage the registry keys and their values, I want to have a custom ID/Name here. I see other apps like "SentinelOne.WinAgent" there. Does anyone have an idea how this is possible?
I didn't find any information or example C# code about that.
In my appxmanifest, I have the following ({MyApp} is a placeholder):
<Extensions>
    <desktop:Extension Category="windows.toastNotificationActivation">
        <desktop:ToastNotificationActivation ToastActivatorCLSID="EC6E9BC5-CFE6-4740-BDD8-53C497EE57CF" />
    </desktop:Extension>
    <!-- Register COM CLSID -->
    <com:Extension Category="windows.comServer">
        <com:ComServer>
            <com:ExeServer Executable="{MyApp.exe}" DisplayName="{MyApp}" Arguments="--AppNotificationActivated">
                <com:Class 
                    Id="EC6E9BC5-CFE6-4740-BDD8-53C497EE57CF" 
                    DisplayName="{MyApp}" 
                    EnableOleDefaultHandler="true" 
                    ProgId="{My.App}" 
                    VersionIndependentProgId="{My.App.1}"
                    AutoConvertTo="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
                    InsertableObject="false"/>
            </com:ExeServer>
        </com:ComServer>
    </com:Extension>
</Extensions>

Also, I have the following set:
<Application Id="{MyApp}">

The AppNotificationManager:
public void Init()
{
    AppNotificationManager notificationManager = AppNotificationManager.Default;
    notificationManager.NotificationInvoked += OnNotificationInvoked;

    notificationManager.Register();

    m_isRegistered = true;
}

If someone need more code or Iformations just aks please!

I don't think that will be possible. But I'm not very sure about that. Maybe you will need to ask in Github-https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues

I found a Solution.  You can set "int result = SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(appId);" to a Custom appID.
